# issue with spaces in directory name for profile variable

Tags: environment-variables

I am trying to create a variable for a directory that has a space in its name in my profile.

It looks something like:

```
variable=/path/to/directory/with space/; export $variable
```

I have tried many different variations of the below, some of which I probably forgot to add:

```
variable=/path/to/directory/"with space/"; export $variable  
variable=/path/to/directory/"with\ space/"; export $variable  
variable="/path/to/directory/with space/"; export $variable  
variable='/path/to/directory/with space/'; export $variable  
variable='/path/to/directory/with\ space/'; export $variable  
variable=""/path/to/directory/with space/""; export $variable  
variable="'/path/to/directory/with space/'"; export $variable  
variable=/path/to/directory/with\ space/; export $variable  
variable=/path/to/directory/with\\ space/; export $variable  
variable=/path/to/directory/with\\\ space/; export $variable  
variable=/path/to/directory/with\\\\ space/; export $variable
```

I can get it to work with one of the above versions but I have to quote the variable, i.e. `ls "$variable"`. This works and is nice, but I was wondering if anyone knew of a way I can get this to work without having to quote the variable?

Comment: You shall always quote your variables.

Comment: I have another variable that is setup the same way but without a space in the directory name and I do not need to quote it. I.E. 
ls $othervariable

Just trying to understand the difference : )

Comment: Short of disabling word-splitting altogether (by unsetting the `IFS` variable - which will almost certainly have other undesirable consequences) I think your best option is to use a shell such as `zsh` that doesn't word-split variable expansions by default

Comment: Bash splits everything into space delimited words. This happens after expanding variables. To prevent something containing spaces to be split up into separate words (or arguments), you have to quote it. And because you usually don't want that whatever is inside your variables gets split (except some rare cases maybe), it's good practice to always quote all your variables. That way you don't forget doing it in places where it is necessary and it does not hurt otherwise.

Comment: I suppose a workaround would be to setup an alias that always automatically adds the quotes right?

like something along the lines of alias listv= ls "$variable"

Answer (score 0):

For **assigning** the variable, these will work:

```
VARIABLE="/path/to/directory/with space"  # Preferred way
VARIABLE='/path/to/directory/with space'
VARIABLE=/path/to/directory/"with space"
VARIABLE=/path/to/directory/'with space'
VARIABLE=/path/to/directory/with" "space
VARIABLE=/path/to/directory/with' 'space
VARIABLE=/path/to/directory/with\ space
```

For **exporting** it, you need to use its name (`VARIABLE`), not its contents (`$VARIABLE`).

```
export VARIABLE
```

Or do the assignment and export in one line:

```
export VARIABLE="/path/to/directory/with space"
```

For **using** it, [you should always quote it](https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/SC2086), to avoid word-splitting (and globbing in other cases).

```
ls "$VARIABLE"
```

As well, I've written the name in uppercase here since [that's the convention](https://stackoverflow.com/a/673940/4518341) for environment variables (and shell variables like `RANDOM`). And I've left off the trailing slash since it's not needed, and could be confusing in some cases, but this is more personal preference.